# how to speed up enumerate for numpy array / how to enumerate over numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate a lot of random numbers. I've tried using `random.random` but this function is quite slow. Therefore I switched to `numpy.random.random` which is way faster! So far so good. The generated random numbers are actually used to calculate some thing (based on the number). I therefore `enumerate` over each number and replace the value. This seems to kill all my previously gained speedup. Here are the stats generated with `timeit()`:

```
test_random - no enumerate
0.133111953735
test_np_random - no enumerate
0.0177130699158


test_random - enumerate
0.269361019135
test_np_random - enumerate
1.22525310516
```

as you can see, generating the number is almost 10 times faster using numpy, but enumerating over those numbers gives me equal run times.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import random

NBR_TIMES = 10
NBR_ELEMENTS = 100000

def test_random(do_enumerate=False):
    y = [random.random() for i in range(NBR_ELEMENTS)]
    if do_enumerate:
        for index, item in enumerate(y):
            # overwrite the y value, in reality this will be some function of 'item'
            y[index] = 1 + item

def test_np_random(do_enumerate=False):
    y = np.random.random(NBR_ELEMENTS)
    if do_enumerate:
        for index, item in enumerate(y):
            # overwrite the y value, in reality this will be some function of 'item'
            y[index] = 1 + item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer

    t = Timer("test_random()", "from __main__ import test_random")
    print "test_random - no enumerate"
    print t.timeit(NBR_TIMES)

    t = Timer("test_np_random()", "from __main__ import test_np_random")
    print "test_np_random - no enumerate"
    print t.timeit(NBR_TIMES)


    t = Timer("test_random(True)", "from __main__ import test_random")
    print "test_random - enumerate"
    print t.timeit(NBR_TIMES)

    t = Timer("test_np_random(True)", "from __main__ import test_np_random")
    print "test_np_random - enumerate"
    print t.timeit(NBR_TIMES)
```

What's the best way to speed this up and why does `enumerate` slow things down so dramatically?

**EDIT:** the reason I use `enumerate` is because I need both the index and the value of the current element.

Comment: Why not use np.arange(len(y)) instead of enumerate  ?

Comment: because I won't be able to do `y[index] = y_value * some_function`

Comment: Try to change what's inside the for loop, and you should notice that most of the numpy time is used for access and reassignment. It seems that numpy is faster when handles that by itself in C and not with Python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To take full advantage of numpy's speed, you want to create [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) whenever possible. Applying `vectorize` to a function as [mgibsonbr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9793070/577088) suggests is one way to do that, but a better way, if possible, is simply to construct a function that takes advantage of numpy's built-in ufuncs. So something like this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.random(10)
>>> a + 1
array([ 1.29738145,  1.33004628,  1.45825441,  1.46171177,  1.56863326,
        1.58502855,  1.06693054,  1.93304272,  1.66056379,  1.91418473])
>>> (a + 1) * 0.25 / 4
array([ 0.08108634,  0.08312789,  0.0911409 ,  0.09135699,  0.09803958,
        0.09906428,  0.06668316,  0.12081517,  0.10378524,  0.11963655])
```

What is the nature of the function you want to apply across the numpy array? If you tell us, perhaps we can help you come up with a version that uses only numpy ufuncs.

It's also possible to generate an array of indices without using `enumerate`. Numpy provides  [`ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html), which is an iterator, and probably slower, but it also provides [`indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html), which is a very quick way to generate the indices corresponding to the values in an array. So...

```
>>> numpy.indices(a.shape)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

So to be more explicit, you can use the above and combine them using `numpy.rec.fromarrays`:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.random(10)
>>> ind = numpy.indices(a.shape)
>>> numpy.rec.fromarrays([ind[0], a])
rec.array([(0, 0.092473494150913438), (1, 0.20853257641948986),
       (2, 0.35141455604686067), (3, 0.12212258656960817),
       (4, 0.50986868372639049), (5, 0.0011439325711705139),
       (6, 0.50412473457942508), (7, 0.28973489788728601),
       (8, 0.20078799423168536), (9, 0.34527678271856999)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

It's starting to sound like your main concern is performing the operation in-place. That's harder to do using `vectorize` but it's easy with the ufunc approach:

```
>>> def somefunc(a):
...     a += 1
...     a /= 15
... 
>>> a = numpy.random.random(10)
>>> b = a
>>> somefunc(a)
>>> a
array([ 0.07158446,  0.07052393,  0.07276768,  0.09813235,  0.09429439,
        0.08561703,  0.11204622,  0.10773558,  0.11878885,  0.10969279])
>>> b
array([ 0.07158446,  0.07052393,  0.07276768,  0.09813235,  0.09429439,
        0.08561703,  0.11204622,  0.10773558,  0.11878885,  0.10969279])
```

As you can see, numpy performs these operations in-place.

Comment: I need both index and value. your `numpy.indices()` solution will only give me the indices.

Comment: Sure, it provides the indices, and `a` provides the values.

Comment: @memyself, you need to say more about the function that you want to map over the variables. When you say "I need both the index and the value of the current element," do you mean that `somefunc` uses both, or that you need the index of the current element to assign to the array? (Because the latter is invalid for ufuncs.)

Comment: so what I want to do is something like this: `y[index] = somefunc(y_value)` where `y_value = item` as defined in my original problem description.

Comment: @memyself, then you don't need the indices at all. Just use `vectorize` somefunc or write a ufunc as illustrated above. Is the problem that you want not to create a copy? Operations like `+=` are performed in-place on numpy arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Check [numpy.vectorize](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#vectorize), it should let you apply arbitrary functions to numpy arrays. For your simple example, you'd do something like this:

```
vecFunc = vectorize(lambda x: x + 1)
vecFunc(y)
```

However, that will create a new numpy array instead of modifying it in-place (which may or may not be a problem in your particular case).

In general, you'll always be better manipulating numpy structures with numpy functions than iterating with python functions, since the former are not only optimized but implemented in C, while the latter will be always interpreted.